# Decentralized exchange that lets you cash out Ether for fiat money?

Tags: exchanges, decentralized-exchange, anonymity, identity, kyc

- [Uniswap](https://uniswap.org/) is a decentralized exchange that doesn't require KYC or ID
  for trading between ETH and ERC-20 tokens (altcoins), while
- [Bisq](https://bisq.network/) is a decentralized exchange that doesn't require KYC or ID for
  cashing out Bitcoin for fiat money.

Is there a similar exchange that doesn't require KYC or ID for cashing out Ethereum for fiat?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to exchange crypto for fiat it's not possible to do this in a decentralized way. If your concern is KYC then some options are more private than others.

There is always the option of using a major exchange like Binance and Kraken, but there will be quite a bit of verification involved here.

Other option is to do this peer-to-peer (P2P) where there will still be KYC (in most cases) but this is enforced by the sellers more than by platform itself. A lot of KYC requirements imposed by traders also depend on local laws so they vary from country to country.

This is a [good list](https://www.reddit.com/r/P2PMoon/comments/ovg2q6/list_of_bitcoin_persontoperson_p2p_bitcoin/) of P2P exchanges today but new ones are coming out every day.

Major exchanges are supporting P2P now too, but number of scams in some of them (eg. Binance) is a lot higher and this may have to do with lack of KYC requirements so it's worth keeping that in mind. Finally, it's worth checking if trading platform is non-custodial which means you have control of your funds in case platform goes down or blocks access for whatever reason. Few examples of non-custodial platforms:  [localcryptos](http://localcryptos.com), [p2pmoon](https://p2pmoon.com), [localcoinswap](https://localcoinswap.com). Localbitcoins on the other hand isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**localcryptos.com**](https://localcryptos.com/), which is a non-custodial crypto marketplace where people buy and sell crypto on their own terms, using any payment method (so it's a kind of peer-to-peer marketplace).